# Optional filter to Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query (ef core) that selects all employees from the employee table:

```
 var employeesQuery = from d in _context.Employees
                      orderby d.LastName, d.FirstName
                      select d;
```

This works perfectly. Except, now I need to add an optional filter.

I am using the select list to choose a supervisor for the current employee. Obviously, I do not want the user to be able to select an employee as their own supervisor. So, I need to filter that employee form the list.

The current employeeid will be passed to the method as an optional parameter. If the parameter is null, no filtering is required; otherwise, filter out the current employeeid.

Comment: This OP question-and-answer-pair is arguably a borderline _wiki article_. SO is not a wiki.  In fact it reads more like a _diary_. [ask].  Was it really necessary to post something just for a `where` clause?

Comment: Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
      var employeesQuery = from d in _context.Employees
                      orderby d.LastName, d.FirstName
                      where d.EmployeeID != CurrentEmployeeID
                      select d;
```

and it works perfectly.

Comment: This OP question-and-answer-pair is arguably a borderline _wiki article_.  SO is not a wiki. [ask].  Was it really necessary to post something just for a `where` clause?

Comment: @MickyD Technically, no. However, while I was posting the question, the answer came to me. And I decided if I had the question, others might as well. There is an option on the ask question page that allows one to answer their own question and it says it can be used to help others. So, that's what I did. I am truly sorry if I offended your sensibilities.

Comment: No offence taken.  We here at SO just don't want it to turn into another MS Social forum